# Simple PL/SQL Package Procedure call. Error: Expect one of the following := . ( @ % ;

Tags: oracle, plsql

Using TOAD for Oracle, I am able to successfully execute this package procedure which accepts a single date argument.

```
EXEC COMMERCIAL_PURGE.PERFORM_PURGE (date'2010-04-10');
```

But I am not able to execute the same statement if I surround it y a BEGIN/END block

```
BEGIN
    EXEC COMMERCIAL_PURGE.PERFORM_PURGE (date'2010-04-10');
END;
/
```

I haven't done PL-SQL coding in over a decade and even then I didn't do that much. What I am trying to do is this:

```
DECLARE
    v_CUTOFF_DT DATE;

    BEGIN

    --SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

    SELECT FIN_IT_RPT.COMMERCIAL_PURGE.GET_PURGE_CUT_OFF_DT INTO v_CUTOFF_DT FROM DUAL;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('The v_CUTOFF_DT=' || v_CUTOFF_DT);

    EXEC FIN_IT_RPT.COMMERCIAL_PURGE.PERFORM_PURGE (v_CUTOFF_DT);

    END;
    /
```

And my understanding is that the declared variables belongs outside of the BEGIN END block.

The error that I get is this:

```
ORA-06550: line 11, column 6:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FIN_IT_RPT" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "FIN_IT_RPT" to continue.
```

What do I have to do to be able to successfully pass a date variable into the PERFORM_PURGE procedure?

Comment: EXEC is a SQL*Plus command. It is not valid within PL/SQL.

Comment: Im finding that Pl/sql seems to be a richer extension of Sql than T-sql but the error messages suck. In ssms, I usually get a red squiggly that usually tells me exactly the issue.

Comment: Showing you the "red squigglies" is the job of your client tool, not the database. It pointed to the exact line and column in the error message.

Comment: Yeah, but it's the job of the database not to give a crappy error message

Comment: You reckon it should include part of the SQL*Plus parser as well, just so it can tell you what went wrong in this particular instance? Or what msg were you expecting?

Comment: If it does recognize "exec" then I would have expected that the error message would have said so.

Comment: That's just it - exec is not pl/sql so you can't expect the parser to recognise it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use EXEC inside the `Begin END` block.

Remove the EXEC from the begin end block. It should work fine then.